# Looking for a small open-source PHP CMS to improve my PHP skill

Tags: php, open-source, content-management-system

I have finished a small PHP website and have an urge to learn something new, systematize to improve my PHP skill. Hence, I'm looking for a small open-source PHP CMS which is well-written and small-size that I could read the source code through and learn a lot from it.

Could you recommend one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know wich one is the best, but you can find some links here :

http://mashable.com/2007/07/30/content-management-systems/